# Python: How to make multiple string sublists from sentence elements in list?

Tags: python, string, list, for-loop

So this is my first list:

```
listone = [
           'Every day Miss Leeson went out to work', 
           ' At night she brought home papers with handwriting on them and made copies with her typewriter', 
           ' Sometimes she had no work at night, and then she would sit on the steps of the high stoop with the other roomers', 
           ' Miss Leeson was not intended for a sky-light room when the plans were drawn for her creation', 
           ' She was gay-hearted and full of tender, whimsical fancies', 
           ' Once she let Mr', 
           ' Skidder read to her three acts of his great (unpublished) comedy, "It'
          ]
```

In this list every sentence is an element, i would like to make every sentence a sublist, or only parts of the sentence a sublist, for example:

```
listtwo = [['Every','Miss','work'], ['At', 'she', 'with'] etc.]
```

The words in the sublists were chosen are random, i already have a filtering function to use for that.

Thanks you for the help!

Comment: it will be in group of three in each sublist?? always from original list

Comment: `[s.split() for s in listone]`

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the `map` function:

```
>>> map(str.split, listone)
[['Every', 'day', 'Miss', 'Leeson', 'went', 'out', 'to', 'work'], ['At', 'night', 'she', 'brought', 'home', 'papers', 'with', 'handwriting', 'on', 'them', 'and', 'made', 'copies', 'with', 'her', 'typewriter'], ['Sometimes', 'she', 'had', 'no', 'work', 'at', 'night,', 'and', 'then', 'she', 'would', 'sit', 'on', 'the', 'steps', 'of', 'the', 'high', 'stoop', 'with', 'the', 'other', 'roomers'], ['Miss', 'Leeson', 'was', 'not', 'intended', 'for', 'a', 'sky-light', 'room', 'when', 'the', 'plans', 'were', 'drawn', 'for', 'her', 'creation'], ['She', 'was', 'gay-hearted', 'and', 'full', 'of', 'tender,', 'whimsical', 'fancies'], ['Once', 'she', 'let', 'Mr'], ['Skidder', 'read', 'to', 'her', 'three', 'acts', 'of', 'his', 'great', '(unpublished)', 'comedy,', '"It']]
```

And chain it with your filter function (in this case, select 3 random words)

```
>>> import random
>>> map(lambda x: random.sample(x, 3), map(str.split, listone))
[['Every','Miss','work'], ['At', 'she', 'with'] etc.]
```

(or, with list comprehension:)

```
>>> [random.sample(x.split(), 3) for x in listone]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a list comprehension with `split` to break up the sentences

```
>>> [i.split() for i in listone]
[['Every', 'day', 'Miss', 'Leeson', 'went', 'out', 'to', 'work'],
 ['At', 'night', 'she', 'brought', 'home', 'papers', 'with', 'handwriting', 'on', 'them', 'and', 'made', 'copies', 'with', 'her', 'typewriter'],
 ['Sometimes', 'she', 'had', 'no', 'work', 'at', 'night,', 'and', 'then', 'she', 'would', 'sit', 'on', 'the', 'steps', 'of', 'the', 'high', 'stoop', 'with', 'the', 'other', 'roomers'],
 ['Miss', 'Leeson', 'was', 'not', 'intended', 'for', 'a', 'sky-light', 'room', 'when', 'the', 'plans', 'were', 'drawn', 'for', 'her', 'creation'],
 ['She', 'was', 'gay-hearted', 'and', 'full', 'of', 'tender,', 'whimsical', 'fancies'],
 ['Once', 'she', 'let', 'Mr'],
 ['Skidder', 'read', 'to', 'her', 'three', 'acts', 'of', 'his', 'great', '(unpublished)', 'comedy,', '"It']]
```

You can also use `filter` in the list comprehension to apply your filter function to remove the unwanted words.

Comment: OP does't want like that i think

Comment: What makes you think that?

Comment: I think from every sentence OP want three random word in sublist

Comment: No, they randomly picked words in their example. They said they have a filter function to select the words. So they can use `map` or `filter` for that.

Comment: Thanks for the great and fast respons, i feel dumb now, but happy.

Answer (score 0):

if you want 3 random from each sentence :

```
 def get_random(a):
     return random.sample(a,3)
 [ get_random(x.split()) for x in listone ]
 '''or using map function'''
 map(get_random,map(str.split,listone))
```

output:

```
[['to', 'went', 'out'], ['on', 'At', 'with'], ['she', 'and', 'would'], ['her', 'room', 'were'], ['tender,', 'was', 'full'], ['Mr', 'let', 'Once'], ['Skidder', 'her', '(unpublished)']]
```

Comment: its `random.randint`, it can choose same integer again